# iOS: What size and how do Iinsert icons for my app in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm confused now. When I checked the developer homepage of apple I found certain dimensions for icons (such as 29x29,57x57,58x58) etc. I hired a friend of mine to make these icons and launch images. However when I go now to project settings in Xcode I find only the dimensions 120x120 for an icon (and only retina).

So my questions:
1. Where do I set my icons, launch images (duration of launch image) etc. correctly?
2. What are now really the dimensions needed? I'm confused since I have now obviously all wrong image sizes...

Answer (score 2):

these are the images that you need, Xcode 5 in "general" you can insert all image, or you can use Asset Catalog, anyway the size of the icons are as follows::

[image]

[image]